# Smallest subgroups with trivial centralizer?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a countable group with trivial center. Define $k(G)$ to be the smallest value of $k$ such that there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ generated by $k$ elements having trivial centralizer in $G$, and $k(G)=\infty$ if no such subgroup exists. Is there a name for this invariant of $G$? Have its properties been studied?

My motivation comes from working on the automorphism group of a shift of finite type (see *The Automorphism Group of a Shift of Finite Type*, Trans. AMS **306** (1988), 71-114 by Boyle, me, and Rudolph), where $k(G)$ may give some insight into unsolved problems such as whether the automorphism groups of the 2-shift and 3-shift are isomorphic as groups.

Comment: in the notation $k(G)$, usually $k$ is not a variable... but as you like!

Comment: Yes that can mean the group ring, but I don't think there's any danger here of confusion!

Comment: I guess there is a long list of such invariants (the smallest cardinal of a subset whose centralizer has some given smallness property etc); in a linear group one can consider the smallest cardinal of a subset generating Zariski-dense subgroup (e.g. I guess it's 2 whenever the group is not virtually solvable, and hence "$k(G)$" (I don't get used sorry, it sounds to my brain like saying "let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the field of complex numbers") would equal 2 if I'm correct. Another related object is the length of chains of centralizers (one can consider the sup, or the infimum among saturated chains).

Comment: In Halmos's essay *How to Write Mathematics*   he talks about "frozen notation," asking "Who would dare write 'Let 6 be a group'?"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number $k(G)$ is the domination number of the non-commuting graph of $G$. 
See Proposition 2.14 of [J. Algebra, 298 (2006) 468–492].

By Corollary 2.17 of [J. Algebra, 298 (2006) 468–492], if $k(H)$ is finite for some finite index subgroup $H$ of $G$, then $k(G)$ is also finite.

Another meaning for $k(G)$ is the minimum number of elements defining the inner automorphism group of the group $G$ (with trivial center). You may find it in the following paper:

Giovanni Cutolo and Chiara Nicotera, Subgroups defining automorphisms in locally nilpotent groups, Forum Mathematicum, Volume 15, Issue 4, (2003) 489-506.

Donwload the latter paper from

http://www.dma.unina.it/cutolo/papers/Forum03.pdf

Comment: link to article: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186930600113X

Comment: Thanks very much for the useful and interesting reference!